# Composite Components - send more than one f:setPropertyActionListener jsf2

Tags: java, jsf

I am trying to create a custom component that recieves a link and adds style class.

In the original link, that the user may have `f:setPropertyActionListener` more than once.

I don't want to create propertyActionListenerValue1 and propertyActionListenerTarget1 propertyActionListenerValue2 propertyActionListenerTarget2 etc for each one.

How can I recieve it in something like `actionProperties="name:Daniel,surname:Smith"` where name and surname represent name and Daniel and Smith represent value and in my composite element I will be able to send it as
`<f:setPropertyActionListener value="name" target="Daniel" />` for each of them?

It can be that the user will send an object as name, and not only a String

Answer (score 2):

In JSF 2.0 you can use the recent EL (2.2), which allows you to pass arguments to methods. I.e.

```
 action="bean.method('value2', 'value2')"
```

So no need of action listeners.

Comment: thanks, but in my commandLink I don't have any action, 
only sets propeties values.
How can I sets the all values at once ?